# What number format or notation is 01h?

Tags: numbers

I was reviewing this [NEC document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjABahUKEwi4-drijdrHAhWTKogKHd2CBpk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.necdisplay.com%2Fdocuments%2FUserManuals%2FRS232_PJ_ControlCommands.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE_PPeJt2Uw3Tou3JOPku1_g2NjmA&sig2=bvMSGi68cl9ScDQqCxwDGg&bvm=bv.101800829,d.cGU) for programming a projector which shows RS232 command examples using number formats such as: `20h + 81h + 01h + 60h + 01h + 00h = 103h` from other sections in the document it would seem that h = 15, though I could be wrong.

I'm a bit embarrassed to ask, but what number format is this? `20h` or `103h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

That means 16 instead of 10 as number base.
So the numbers are 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F.

Adding 20h + 81h equals A1h
or 32 + 129 = 161.

Other notations are `0x00` (C languages)

Answer (score 2):

It's hexadecimal

20h == 0x20 == 32

I hadn't seen this kind of notation in a while. I remember it being used for old PC BIOS/DOS interrupt tables: http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html

Answer (score 2):

It's hex.

20h = 32

01h = 1

Similar to the 0x notation. E.g. 0x20 = 20h = 32.

Answer (score 2):

In Section 2.1 of the document you linked:

> Command/response A series of strings enclosed in a frame represents a
>   command or response **(in hexadecimal notation)**.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the info was in the document. I was particularly thrown by the command table listing POWER ON == 15, POWER OFF == 16 and INPUT SW CHANGE as 18. The examples for all of those commands show 00h, 01h and 03h respectively; I was looking for the h to equal 15 so those values would match.